# Maven installing plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

```
[INFO] `Scanning for projects`...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] `Building MVNDEMO 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] `BUILD FAILURE`
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] `Total time: 0.099 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-25T12:29:22+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/123M`
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "testcases". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You called something like `mvn testcases`, which is not a valid Maven phase.

If you want to build, use `mvn clean install`.